# best control to display div element winforms C#

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I am trying to display a div element in winform solution, searching for good control from the basic/devexpress controls to display div elements but I can't find any.

is there any idea how I can display the dev elements without using web browser control

Comment: What do you mean by "div"? HTML markup?

Comment: Yes Html snippet code

Comment: If you want to display HTML, you need a control capable of displaying HTML. Why don't you want to use the WebBrowser control, and what alternatives have you found?

Comment: ok gonna try that !